# How do I add a bearer token into chrome driver as a header argument by using selenium and python?

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver, bearer-token

I was trying to open a URL which requires a bearer token as a header argument:
[image: the header file shows the URL needs a bearer token which is generated after each login]

I think the easiest way is added the bearer token into chrome driver.
I have checked this website ([the website](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)) which shows the arguments of chrome driver but I could not find a way to do it.

I can successfully open the URL(response JSON data)If I use postman by adding bearer token into Authorization:
[image]

Otherwise, it will show the following info if without bearer token:

[image]

So the problem is how do I add the bearer token into chrome driver so that I can obtain the JSON data?